# How does PreparedStatement.executeQuery work?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, jdbc

How `PreparedStatement.executeQuery` works? Does it fetch results from database and I loop through them? Or it fetches the first result, and on record.next continues with sql query to the next row?

```
ResultSet record = statement.executeQuery("select * from users");
    while (record.next()) {
    //do something
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation:

[Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29)

> ```
> public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet
>   object.

[ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

> A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually
>   generated by executing a statement that queries the database.
>
> ```
> public boolean next() throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Moves the cursor down one row from its current position. A ResultSet
>   cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to
>   the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call
>   makes the second row the current row, and so on.
>
> If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the
>   method next will implicitly close it. A ResultSet object's warning
>   chain is cleared when a new row is read.

---

As a representation this means the statement is executed once and when iterated is iterated over the result of that execution.

---

But how the result from database is handled depends really on the implementation. To make a contrast I will refer two databases MSSQL, MYSQL.

### MSSQL

The documentation of MSSQL driver that comments exactly how the results are handled you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379039.aspx):

> There are two types of result sets: client-side and server-side.
>
> Client-side result sets are used when the results can fit in the
>   client process memory. These results provide the fastest performance
>   and are read by the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server in their
>   entirety from the database. These result sets do not impose additional
>   load on the database by incurring the overhead of creating server-side
>   cursors. However, these types of result sets are not updatable.
>
> Server-side result sets can be used when the results do not fit in the
>   client process memory or when the result set is to be updatable. With
>   this type of result set, the JDBC driver creates a server-side cursor
>   and fetches rows of the result set transparently as the user scrolls
>   through it.

### MySQL

MySql implementation of JDBC interface that you can read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory.
>   In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate, and due to
>   the design of the MySQL network protocol is easier to implement. If
>   you are working with ResultSets that have a large number of rows or
>   large values, and cannot allocate heap space in your JVM for the
>   memory required, you can tell the driver to stream the results back
>   one row at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it correctly. It fetches the entire results from your query, and you loop through them.
The internal pointer, or cursor, initially starts *before* the first row, so calling `record.next()` will move it to the first row.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29