# What does a ResultSet object look like?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Is it like an array or is it like a database/excel table ? Or something else ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11694152/1001027) gives a good idea on how it is handled.

Comment: You can examine it in your debugger and look at all the fields and their values and those fields values etc.  Its different for each JDBC driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from javadocs:

> A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries the database.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to know that is to look at the javadoc here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

In the javadoc you have code sample to get and use such objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is JDBC driver dependant, `ResultSet` is just an interface. But in principle the closest you can get is an `Iterator`. `ResultSet` gives you one result at a time and allows to query whether there are any more results. Theoretically `ResultSet` can fetch one record at a time as well.